# How to take a simple list of integers and modify it to a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I already have a list of integers:

```
lst = [120, 250, 310]
```

And after some calculations i need to append each new result to the integer i used. There is a for loop which encapsulates the whole thing. So after something like that:

```
for item in lst:
    for ke, va in somedict.items():
        if (item + va) in someotherdict:
            lst = ?here is where i'm stuck
```

I need the result to be:

```
lst = [[120,110], [250,200], [310,330]]
```

in the next loop:

```
lst = [[120,110,150], [250,200,180], [310,330,99]]
```

etc... any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first convert your list of integers to a list of lists of integers:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
  lst[i] = [lst[i]]
```

Then you can append to each:

```
for itemlist in lst:
    item = itemlist[0]
    for ke, va in somedict.items():
        if (item + va) in someotherdict:
            itemlist.append(somevalue)
```

Comment: Or shorter `lst = [[x] for x in lst]`

Comment: @Vaughn Cato It returns "for i in range(lst):
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got list."

Comment: @fractal_7: oops -- fixed

Comment: yeap now it works, also the comprehension @kigurai is correct.

Comment: @fractal_7: ok -- it wasn't clear to me whether modifying the existing list in place was important or not

Comment: @Vaughn Cato in this "item = itemlist[0]" you select the first sublist right ? so i need to itarate in the next loop and increase it?

Comment: @fractal_7: it is picking the first (any only) item out of the inner list.